# ssh over ssh without confirmation

Tags: ssh

I try to execute ssh over ssh:

```
ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' 10.10.x1.x -A ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' 10.10.x2.x sudo docker inspect routed | 10.x.x.x
```

I get "Connection to 10.10.x1.x closed."

When I do it with a first "-o 'StrictHostKeyChecking" only:

```
ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' 10.10.x1.x -A ssh 10.10.x2.x sudo docker inspect routed | 10.x.x.x
```

it's working, but I need to SSH without confirmation on two hosts, how can I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution:

```
 ssh -t -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' 10.10.x1.x -A "ssh-keyscan 10.10.x2.x &>/dev/null && ssh -q -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no'10.10.x2.x ls -la"
```

by ssh-keyscan I can reach another host without confirmation